# How to switch xsessions?

Tags: x11, desktop

I run xmonad/slock/lxdm currently, and I cannot find a way to get a "switch user" system working. Here's what I'd like:

- key combination returns me to login (applications still run in the background)
- another user can log in to a different desktop environment/window manager (e.g. GNOME, openbox)
- other DE's switch user feature will let me get back into my existing session

I know I can use virtual terminals and avoid the whole issue, but I'd really prefer to have it work like other DEs. I'm completely ok with switching login managers or screen lockers.

What utilities exist for managing something like this?